# Subdomains not taking effect CentOS

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, subdomain

Hey I'm using webmin to manage the apache server on my CentOS box and I'm trying to set my subdomains to a different directory. However the subdomain and the actual domain both go to the exact same page

```
<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot "/home/windshear-gaming.com/public_html/forum"
ServerName forum.windshear-gaming.com
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
DocumentRoot "/home/windshear-gaming.com/public_html/portal"
ServerName windshear-gaming.com
</VirtualHost>
```

Thats how I setup the virtual hosts for the two different subdomains. Everything else was just left the same.

Answer (score 2):

In your /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
### Section 3: Virtual Hosts
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin username@domain.tld
    DocumentRoot /home/windshear-gaming.com/public_html/portal
    ServerName windshear-gaming.com
    ErrorLog logs/windshear-gaming.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/windshear-gaming.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin username@domain.tld
    DocumentRoot /home/windshear-gaming.com/public_html/forum
    ServerName forum.windshear-gaming.com
    ErrorLog logs/forum.windshear-gaming.com-error_log
    CustomLog logs/forum.windshear-gaming.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

That will answer your domain and subdomain in every IP your webserver is listening to correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using name based virtual hosts but matching against everything with the following line: `<Virtualhost *>`. I bet they both go to the option configured last, correct? Try using: `<Virtualhost forum.windshear-gaming.com>` and `<Virtualhost windshear-gaming.com>`